# Limiting probability that the sum of the values of a die is a multiple of 13

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

A fair die is thrown repeatedly. Let $X_n$ denote the sum of the $n$ first throws. I have to find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(X_n \text{ is multiple of 13})$. Now follows what I tried, which I don't think is really efficient:

We can look modulo 13 and then we have an irreducible Markov chain on a finite state-space which is aperiodic (because for $n>2$ and for all $i,j\in\{1,2,...,13\}$ it is clear that $p_{ij}^{(n)}>0$, this is the $n$-step probability). So by Convergence to equilibrium we have that the asked limit actually exists. Now for calculating it, we have to find an invariant distribution of a matrix of dimensions 13 by 13. The matrix looks like $$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
0& 1/6 & 1/6 &1/6 & \dots\\
0&0&1/6&1/6&\dots\\
0& 0&0&1/6&\dots\\
\dots&\dots&\dots&\dots&\dots
\end{array}\right)$$
This is easily done by a computer, but I think this exercise can be done more efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Markov chain of the residues mod $13$ is irreducible and aperiodic on the finite state space $\mathbb Z/13\mathbb Z$ and its transitions are invariant by translation hence the unique stationary distribution is uniform. Thus, for every $i$, $P(X_n=i\pmod{13})\to\frac1{13}$ when $n\to\infty$.

In particular, $P(13\ \text{divides}\ X_n)\to\frac1{13}$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: thanks! this is a very nice answer :)

Comment: That doesn't work for a 1-sided die, but then again neither does my answer.

Comment: @Michael "1-sided die" ??

Comment: There is no steady state if every roll is 1.

Comment: @Michael I got your point the first time. It is irrelevant.

Comment: @Did translationally invariant doesn't imply the uniqueness of stationary states.. $\pi_i = \sum_j \pi_j p_{j i} $

Comment: @Brish True. And irrelevant. Please read carefully the answer.

Comment: @Did you are saying 'transitions are invariant by translation hence the unique stationary distribution is uniform.'  what do you mean by this statement? .. Please clarify.

Comment: @Brish No I am not saying that, I am saying that "The Markov chain is irreducible and aperiodic on the finite state space ℤ/13ℤ and its transitions are invariant by translation hence the unique stationary distribution is uniform." [Irreducible + aperiodic + finite state space + transitions invariant by translation] $\implies$ [Existence of stationary distribution + uniqueness of stationary distribution + uniform stationary distribution].

Comment: @Did Thanks for the clarification. How does one prove the above implication. Can you point me to a reference or a hint. Thanks

Comment: @Brish Basics of finite Markov chains.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_i$ be the greatest of the steady-state $p_j(j=0..12)$.
$p_i=(p_{i-1}+...+p_{i-6})/6$, so all of $p_{i-1}$ to $p_{i-6}$ must equal $p_i$.  (None are greater, and if any were less then $p_i$ would be less as well.)
So $p_i,p_{i-1},...,p_{i-6}$ are equal and the greatest of the $p_j$.
For the same reason, $p_{i-6}=(p_{i-7}+...+p_{i-12})/6$, and the other $p_j$ are the same as well.
So all $p_j$ are equal in the steady state.

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit more, because I dont understand what you mean exactly.